# How do I set equal character spacing in AvalonEdit such that visual line columns are the same as document line columns

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm wrapping AvalonEdit into a custom control and I'm trying to display a text file using equal character spacing such that it behaves similarly to notepad. I've done quite a bit of digging but I can't seem to find which property I need to flip to get equal character spacing.

Thanks

Comment: It is a font property. Some fonts are of equal width, while others aren't. You can user Consolas, Lucida Console, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix here. I found that if I just change the font to Consolas it works out just fine. I'm going to stick to this for now.